# Как открыть приложению доступ не только к медиафайлам, а ко всем файлам? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Даю разрешения так:

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ){
            val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ){
            val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,0)
        }
```

Итого даны разрешения `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Но в настройках разрешений приложений в самом Android всё равно выбранным показан пункт "**Разрешить доступ только к медиафайлам**". Нужно же, чтобы был выбран переставляющийся на той же странице пункт "**Разрешить управление всеми файлами**".
Обычно приложение пересылает просто на этот список, где надо собственноручно выбрать этот пункт. Как такое сделать?

Comment: а манифест добавили?

Comment: @IR42 да. Всё в манифесте есть